# How can I create 1000 columns of random variables using each row's mean and SD

Tags: python, numpy, loops, random, quantile

My dataframe looks like this:

| City | Mean | SD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Newcastle | 60 | 0.81 |
| Liverpool | 62 | 0.91 |
| Cardiff | 65 | 0.87 |
| Glasgow | 59 | 0.86 |

I want to add column 'n' which contains new random values using the Mean and SD column values. I've done this before using:

`df['n'] = np.random.normal(df['Mean'], df['SD'])`

I then want to add a second column which generates a quintile rank based on the value in 'n'. I've done this using:

`df['q'] = pd.qcut(df['n'], 5, labels = False)`

| City | Mean | SD | n | q | n+1 | q+1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Newcastle | 60 | 0.81 | 57 | 5 | 55 | 5 |
| Liverpool | 62 | 0.91 | 61 | 1 | 57 | 4 |
| Cardiff | 65 | 0.87 | 60 | 1 | 61 | 1 |
| Glasgow | 59 | 0.86 | 55 | 3 | 58 | 3 |

I would like to loop these two steps to add 2000 columns, 1000 'n' columns (named 'n+1') and a 1000 'q' columns (named 'q+1').

Comment: Does one of the solutions answer your question? If so, you should accept an answer rather than leaving the question without an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved using:

```
mean = df['Mean']
std_dev = df['SD']
dist = np.random.normal(mean, std_dev)

for i in range(1000):
    col_name = 'col_' + str(i)
    df[col_name] = np.random.normal(dist)'
    
    col_name_q = 'col_q_' + str(i)
    df[col_name_q] = pd.qcut(df[col_name], 5, labels = False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using numpy to create all the random numbers in one call. Once you add those to the DataFrame, you can use `qcut` on each of those new columns and add those as well. This doesn't require any (explicit) `for` loops.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"Mean":[60, 62, 65, 59],
        "STD":[0.81, 0.91, 0.87, 0.86]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

N = 10
n_col_names = [f"n+{i+1}" for i in range(N)]
q_col_names = [f"q+{i+1}" for i in range(N)]

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
df[n_col_names] = rng.normal(df["Mean"], df["STD"], size=(N, df.shape[0])).T
df[q_col_names] = df[n_col_names].apply(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 5, labels=False))
```